# Using location.hash w/jquery in Drupal and not 'doubling' url

Tags: jquery, drupal-6

I have a page with a 5-tab system on a page. Each tab has a link on in a left-hand side navigation list so that someone can either link directly to the page with a specific tab opened, or click on any tab itself to show the contents hide/the other.

To do this, I am using the location.hash and appending each tabs ID to the url like:

```
http://localhost:8082/departments/site-facilities/enviroment/iso-14001#impactAreas
```

so someone can hit just:

```
http://localhost:8082/departments/site-facilities/environment
```

..see the tab system and click on the iso-14001 tab which adds the hash to the url, or they can enter that url above or click on a link in a left-hand nav bar.

The problem I'm having in Drupal is that in the basic html list (this is a extra list, not the Primary nor Secondary menu) I have entered in the a hrefs links like:

```
< a href="/departments/site-facilities/environment/iso-14001#impactAreas">link here</a>
```

Which works if somewhere else in the site. However, once a person is on the actual page with tabs should they click on a left-list nav link, the url in the browser becomes:

```
http://localhost:8082/departments/site-facilities/departments/site-facilities/environment/iso-14001#impactAreas
```

So it's like Drupal isn't recognizing to reload a new page and is just appending the href location to the existing url.

I'm not sure why, if this is a php thing and hashes, if I need different jquery etc.

Here is the basic jquery I put together:

```
function setupSubNav(){
  pathName = window.location.href;
  $('.hiddenSection').css('display','none');
  pathArray = pathName.split('#');
  param = pathArray[pathArray.length-1];
  if(pathArray.length>1){
    showSection(param,$('.' + param + 'Trigger'));
  }
  else
  {
     if ($('body.fervens-a .pageTabs li')) {
        var sectionName = $($('body.fervens-a .pageTabs li')[0]).attr('class').split('Trigger')[0];
            showSection(sectionName, $($('body.fervens-a .pageTabs li')[0]));
        }
  }
    $('body.fervens-a .pageTabs li').click(function(){
        if (!($(this).hasClass('current'))) {
            var sectionName = $(this).attr('class').split('Trigger')[0];
            showSection(sectionName, $(this));
        }
    });
}
function showSection(sectionName,$navObj) {
    if (sectionName != 'iso14001' && sectionName != 'environmentalPolicy' && sectionName != 'impactAreas' && sectionName != 'goals2013' && sectionName != 'isoDocs') {
        sectionName = 'iso14001';
        $navObj = $($('body.fervens-a .pageTabs li')[0]);
    }
        $('body.fervens-a .pageTabs li').removeClass('current');
        $navObj.addClass('current');
        $('.hiddenSection').css('display','none');
        $('#' + sectionName + 'Content').css('display','block');
        window.location.hash = sectionName;
}
```

Should I be somehow checking if the window.location already has a hash and if so remove it before adding the new one? Doesn't sound right but I'm stuck as to why this doesn't work.

I used previous code I previously wrote for a Schwab mini-site and just added the hash stuff but it was all html over there and now that this is Drupal and in php, I'm just wondering what else I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy cow. It was as simple as using a "?" instead of a "#".

Well, that's how we learn. Thanks for looking.